# In a Hierarchical Bayesian Model, how can we sample and see how a prior distribution looks like if it contains hyperparameters with hyperpriors?

Tags: bayesian, multilevel-analysis, prior, hierarchical-bayesian

I have a Bayesian Hierarchical Model that looks like:

\begin{equation}
Y_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2) \\
\mu \sim N(\mu_0, \sigma_0^2) \\
\sigma^2 \sim Gamma(1,1) \\
\mu_0 \sim N(0,1) \\
\sigma_0^2 \sim Gamma(2,2)\\
\end{equation}

In this set-up, I have found the posterior of $\mu$ and am trying to compare it to how the prior of $\mu$ looks like on a density plot to view shrinkage.

I am not sure how to construct the prior density of $\mu$ via sampling since it doesn't have fixed hyperparameters.

I thought about the following code in R:

```
mu0 <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
sigma02 <- rgamma(100,2,2)
mu <- rnorm(100,mu0,sigma02)
```

But am not sure if I am properly doing the average, as it seems very spread out. Instead, should I take the mean of `mu0` and `sigma02` and plug them in like so?

```
mu0 <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
sigma02 <- rgamma(100,2,2)
mu <- rnorm(100,mean(mu0),mean(sigma02))
```

I lose variability here, but I am not sure if either works.

Comment: No the first solution is correct, it shows the diffusive effect of using an hyperprior.